# Nodejs passing res.end() as callback not working

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

Hello I am using connect and have:

```
var app = connect()
 .use(connect.static(directory))
 .use(function(req,res) {
  switch (req.url)
  {
   case '/query':
    exportFunc.query("myquery", res.end);
    break;
  }
}

-- exportFunc.js --
exports.query= function(query, cb) {
 queryServer(query, cb);
}

var queryServer = function(query, cb) {
 cb("MyQueryResult");
}
```

But I get an error that cb cannot be determined what object it is.  Do I need to cast this object into its correct type?

Comment: What exact error do you have ?

Comment: http.js:920  this._implicitHeader();

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_implicitHeader'

and if I try passing the full res.  I get a object type error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not calling the function with the right context (`this` in the function). You can fix it by replacing

```
 exportFunc.query("myquery", res.end);
```

with

```
 exportFunc.query("myquery", res.end.bind(res));
```

or

```
 exportFunc.query("myquery", function(){ res.end() });
```

Comment: on in this case, even `("myquery", () => res.end())`